# Prototyping objects initialized from '{}'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = (function() {
  Function.prototype.extend = function(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
})();

var Helpers = {};

Helpers.prototype.get_random_int = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

Helpers.prototype.clamp = function(value, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
}

module.exports.helpers = Helpers;
```

I am just wanting to create my own helper methods in its own namespace to be included in my code. Is this the right way of going about it? I do get an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'get_random_int' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a constructor, instead of this:

```
  var Helpers = {};
```

use this:

```
function Helpers() {};
```

Oh the other hand, if you just want to define a simple object, remove the prototypes:

```
Helpers.get_random_int = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

Helpers.clamp = function(value, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
}
```

Comment: That isn't exactly what I am looking for. This returns a function which executes the prototyping commands, I want to return an object that has those functions built in.

Comment: The function is being defined, not executed. Also, is there some reason you are defining 'prototype' values if you do not want to define a constructor?

Comment: Yes, but I would have to execute it after importing. Plus it doesn't know what Helpers is because it is just the name of the function, not an object of which to prototype off of.

Comment: Since you used 'prototype', I assumed you wanted Helper to be a constructor. Are you saying you just want Helper to be a simple object?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding how the prototype system works. I want to return an object that has those functions defined in it.